# omitting "that" is "so ... that ..."

Tags: register, optional-that, so

Is it considered informal to omit "that" in "so ... that ..."?
What would style guides say about the following?

> John is so intelligent (that) he can learn any language in two months.

If this omission is used alongside a formal structure, would a stylistic mismatch arise?

> The building is of such size and grandeur, (that) everyone feels great awe when they first see it.

Some style guides, notably The New Fowler's Modern English Usage and The Cambridge Guide to English Usage, both claim *that* should **be retained in formal contexts involving compound conjunctions**. Examples are offered below:

> What would he do now (that) he had missed him in Toulouse?
>
> The heat was up so high (that) almost everyone took off their coats.
>
> We were so exhausted (that) we didn’t care.
>
> They would be there provided (that) we did all the catering.

Do you agree with their judgments on these sentences? If so and if you still think *that* can be omitted in formal contexts involving compound conjunctions, could you provide some working guidelines about its omission?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81176/discussion-on-question-by-apollyon-omitting-that-is-so-that). Any clarification of the question should be edited into the question instead of left in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider it informal or conversational.

> John is so tall he can dunk the ball.
>
> A mourning dove is so fast it can stay ahead of a kestrel.
>
> The ride is so popular people are willing to wait three hours in line.

I think the majority of editors would insert **that** here:

> Economic indicators have been so strong the Federal Reserve has made the decision to raise interest rates a quarter point.

P.S. **of such {noun phrase}** is more formal than **so {adjective}**. With **of such {quality expressed by abstract noun or nouns}** there can be a register shift and even a "clash" if the complement clause isn't introduced by **that**:

> She is a woman of such sustained munificence the museum has been able to assemble a truly remarkable collection of Pre-Raphaelite paintings.

P.P.S. When the main clause becomes more ponderous or "weighty", additional syntactic undergirding is helpful, and so **that** tends to introduce the complement clause.

Comment: Is "be of _abstract noun_ " a formal structure? E.g. _He is of great intelligence_ ? Does it create a clash with _so,,,(that)..._ with _that_ omitted?

Comment: @Apollyon: **a man of great intelligence** is not conversational. I'd need to see the actual sentence to judge whether there's a clash.   The sentences here follow the pattern **so {adjective} {finite clause}**

Comment: There is one such sentence in the OP: _The building is of such size and grandeur, everyone feels great awe when they first see it._

Comment: That's not the pattern:  **of such {noun phrase}** isn't **so {adjective}**

Comment: **of such {noun phrase}** is more formal than **so {adjective}** and IMO there can be a slight clash if **that** does not introduce the complement clause.

Comment: Please see the P.S.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I had answered this question not knowing that the question had several assumptions behind it that were not made clear until comments were added to this answer.

1. The use of **that** is more acceptable in formal writing than informal writing.
2. Formality is better expressed with longer sentences.

I disagree with both of these assumptions. Formal writing can be precise and and follow a stricter set of adherence to grammar, while at the same time exercise style choices that aid comprehension. There is no context that can't benefit from the application of [plain language](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect13&info0=13).

If there is a situation where **that** hinders comprehension because it slows down the parsing of text, and where removing it doesn't damage the grammar, then it doesn't serve a purpose. The need for comprehension is even more important in formal text.

---

Omitting **that** is mostly one of style and, unless you're following a house style guide, it's quite subjective.

It really has little to do with it being informal or formal. Those who would argue against its overuse would want it removed from formal contexts too. In fact, people writing informally will seldom pay attention to the frequent use of **that**. It's actually more likely that those concerned with its overuse would removed it from formal writing than they would from informal writing.

I [answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/455783/291924) a similar question at English Language & Usage. Most of that answer is relevant, so I will quote it here:

> Many people think that **that** should not be overused, and that sentences flow better without it.
>
> From the blog post ["Overuse of That"](https://usaukwoods.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/overuse-of-that/) by Billie Jo Schinnerer:
>
> > My finding is many times it can be deleted without being missed and often increases the flow of the passage. For example in the sentence below:
> >
> > *She found that she did not like the soup.*
> >     *She found she did not like the soup.*
>
> This is, of course, a subjective opinion. Some people may find the first sentence preferable, others the second. (I personally prefer the second sentence—without **that**.) . . .
>
> But different sentences have different cadences, and sometimes it might sound more natural to include **that** in one and exclude it from another. The context in which a sentence exists (its surrounding text) also makes a difference.
>
> ---
>
> There are some legitimate reasons why **that** should *not* be removed.
>
> In the blog post ["When to Delete 'That',"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-delete-that) Neal Whitman (a guest blogger for Mignon Fogarty) gives the following example:
>
> > Sometimes, omitting a "that" after a non-bridge verb goes beyond being slightly awkward and can actually be confusing. Here’s an example from Bryan Garner’s *Modern American Usage*:
> >
> > - Son acknowledges being a member of a minority ... may have helped him turn his eyes abroad early.
> >
> > The trouble here is that "acknowledge" can be a transitive verb. So when a noun phrase comes after it, such as "being a member of a minority," the reader might just take it as a direct object: “Son acknowledges being a member of a minority.” But whoops! The sentence keeps going, and the reader has to go back and reparse it. Garner calls this a miscue; sentences that produce miscues like this are called garden-path sentences.
>
> He goes on to say the following:
>
> > Nouns that sound awkward if you delete a "that" include "fact." A phrase like "the fact Squiggly likes chocolate" is clear enough, but it’s really awkward-sounding.
>
> He finally concludes:
>
> > If you’re a native English speaker, the main rule to follow here is to go by your ear. You probably know what sounds natural and what doesn’t, and all you need to do is give that native-speaker intuition more weight and authority than a rule stating that you should omit "that" whenever possible.
> >
> > If you’re not a native speaker, I recommend keeping the "that" unless you’re dealing with a verb, noun, or adjective that you know will sound good without it. It’s safer to leave it in than to leave it out. As you write and read more, you’ll identify more of the words that allow you to omit "that."

Comment: What about sentences in my context?

Comment: It's a fair answer, but it dodges the question of *formality*.  Apollyon already understands "that" can sometimes be grammatically omitted.  As you say, it's a question of personal style, which is why I recommend the question be edited to be more specific, or else be closed.

Comment: @Andrew Formality is mostly irrelevant to this issue. The prevalent style of removing extraneous instances of **that** applies as much to formal writing as it does to informal writing. In fact, a case could be made for the removal of **that** happening with *more* frequency in formal writing. (Because people tend to not "censor" themselves when writing informally.) If so, the situation is actually the reverse of what's claimed in the question.

Comment: @Apollyon Both versions are fine grammatically with or without the use of **that**. (Without it, a comma should be used.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Here's an excerpt from Robert Burchfield's The New Fowler's Modern English Usage: When the conjunction _that_ is part of the correlative pairs _so ... that, such ... that, now ... that (or so that_, etc.), it is **normally retained in formal writing** but is sometimes omitted in informal contexts, e.g. _What would he do now (that) he had missed him in Toulouse?; The heat was up so high (that) almost everyone took off their coats._

Comment: The Cambridge Guide to English Usage has the comment: In various kinds of adverbial clauses, _that_ is also omitted, depending on the formality of style. This is expecially true when it functions as part of a compound conjunction, for example: 
_We were so exhausted (that) we didn’t care._
_They would be there provided (that) we did all the catering._
The constructions without _that_ present the briskness of speech, rather than the decorum of formal writing.

Comment: @Apollyon I agree that it should be retained in formal writing—but not blindly; only if a particular sentence benefits from its inclusion. Not every sentence does benefit. You can't take a specific example and then apply it to every instance. The use or exclusion of **that** is entirely contextual.

Comment: Could you tell when exactly _that_ should be retained in formal writing and when it should not? Any working guidelines?

Comment: Specifically, could you tell me whether the style guide examples really are improved by _that_. If so, why?