# The movie THAT I want to see is called ... or... the movie I want to see is called

Tags: optional-that

> The movie **that** I want to see is called...

or

> The movie I want to see is called....

From reading up on it I understand that both are grammatically correct, but why is the one without **that** used more? (more matches in Google)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there is much of an answer to any "why" question about English usage.  It's used more because it's more informal, maybe.

Comment: Because it's shorter?

Comment: You might find reading this helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175237/omitting-that-is-so-that There are two really good answers about omitting "that".

Comment: There be some as call it "*wh*iz deletion."